# Testing the Success of a Command Involving Pipes

Tags: shell, scripting, pipe, solaris

What is the best way to test that both the df and awk commands were successful in the following command? Using Solaris.

`df -h /myloc* | awk '{ if ( $5 > 80 ) print $6}' > somelog`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `pipefail` option (it's also supported in `ksh`, the default shell on Solaris):

```
$ if false | true; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
ok
$ set -o pipefail
$ if false | true; then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
failed
```

You can localize that option into a subshell:

```
if (set -o pipefail; false | true); then echo ok; else echo failed; fi
```

(replace `false` and `true` with your respective commands)

Comment: I thought an if statement requires square brackets, but your example doesn't have square brackets and indeed to works. That's a revelation!

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to split them, so that you can store the first output and check the conjunction of the two exit statuses:

```
if OUT1=$(df -h /myloc*) && echo ${OUT1} | awk '{ if ( $5 > 80 ) print $6}' > somelog; then
  echo "success"
else 
  echo "failure"
fi
```